# How to launch MobaXterm from right-click context menu on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, context-menu, mobaxterm

Just like Shift+Right-Click to open a command prompt in that folder, I want to replace the command prompt with MobaXterm on Windows platform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the settings menu, click on the configuration option. A dialog box should appear with several tabs for various settings. In the General tab, there is an option for `Right-click menu on Windows folders`.

If they are already set up, it will ask if you want to uninstall the right-click option.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Herb response, if you want the "Open MobaXterm terminal here" context menu option when right-clicking on the directory background (instead of right-clicking a folder only) you can do add the Windows registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\OpenWithMobaXterm]
@="Open MobaXterm terminal here"
 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\OpenWithMobaXterm\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mobatek\\MobaXterm\\MobaXterm.exe\" -openfolder \"%v\""
```